# Automating Adobe Media Server install

Tags: installation, adobe

everyone!  I'm making an installer that is going to set a machine up for use of a piece of software.  Adobe Media Server is one of the software requirements.  I'm wondering if there's any way to automate the installation of it.  I can, of course, open the wizard through a command line, but at that point, the user needs to be there to continue installation.  I'm really looking for more of a "set it and forget it" type of solution.  If anybody knows of any way this is possible, please tell me.  I'm not finding anything online so far.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are doing this on a Windows server, in which case you will have to do some heavy integration with the Adobe Media Server installer. A good open source tool for installer bundling would be [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php). This is much easier to accomplish on a linux server, where you could execute a function within a script that downloads the installer, and extracts it with defined parameters. I believe the package name for a YUM install on linux is: AdobeMediaServer_5_LS1_linux64.tar.gz

Answer (score 0):

You can search for any installers building tool which supports adding prerequisites and add the Adobe Media Server as a prerequisite to your installer. Also, you should configure your Adobe Media Server prerequisite to be installed with a silent/unattended command line.